# md-icon md-list-icon not showing in angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms

I want to display an icon before the list for which i had used like.

Not sure if the below is supported for Angular2.

The below module 'MaterialModule' is not required i guess, cause after removing it is working for me.

If i import this module, i get: no exported 'MaterialModule'!

**app.module.ts**  //Not required to import here

```
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';

imports: [
   MaterialModule
...
```

**index.html**

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

**test.component.html**

```
 <md-list-item routerLink="2" routerLinkActive="active">
  <md-icon md-list-icon>face</md-icon>  <!--Icon not displaying here!-->

    <div fxFlex="10"></div>
    <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
      <a *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index" href="javascript:; " class="list-group-item " (click)="getProducts(cat._id,i)">{{cat.category_name}}</a>
    </div>

  </md-list-item>
```

my **\src\index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Food4Smiles</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.2.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icon‌​s" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/static/hmicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure u have added materials icon link ```<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">``` in your file.

Comment: Also try with  ```<i class="material-icons">face</i>```..

Comment: Have updated the answer where i have included the src link in my index html , but still no icon reflecting!

Comment: Did u tried using ```<i class="material-icons">face</i>```?

Comment: with <i class  my text style is changing to italics, but no icon again :(

Comment: ok got it now, was using @angular2-material it is depricated..have updated the working answer, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

**index.html**

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

**test.component.html**

```
 <md-list-item routerLink="2" routerLinkActive="active">
  <md-icon md-list-icon>face</md-icon>  <!--Icon not displaying here!-->

    <div fxFlex="10"></div>
    <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
      <a *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index" href="javascript:; " class="list-group-item " (click)="getProducts(cat._id,i)">{{cat.category_name}}
     </a>
   </div>

 </md-list-item>
```

**\src\index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Food4Smiles</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.2.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icon‌​s" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/static/hmicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```